# opencv, python: How to track live trackers from environment and find changes in environment

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib, opencv3.0

I'm trying my hands on OpenCV with Python and 'am kind of stuck.
I want to find specific trackers from every frame of a live camera and detect changes in the environment with a tracker of different color (say red).

Right now, my code takes a frame of my video which I select, and shows trackers which are too much to understand.
Can you help me in fixing this code?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)


    # Initiate feature detector
    orb = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()

    # find the keypoints with ORB
    kp = orb.detect(gray)

    img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, kp, outImage=None, color=(0, 255, 0), flags=0)
    plt.imshow(img2), plt.show()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This is my image without an object (bottle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPgct.png)
[This is me with an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okCfe.png)
Now what I want to track changes in between the images (with bottle and without bottle), i.e changes in environment of an image should be tracked live on videocam!

Comment: I'm not sure if the question actually allows to understand the problem. What is the issue you are facing? What is the problem?

Comment: I want to trace keypoints in my environment so that I can use AR stickers on those objects. Now, the code here is able to take keypoints of a particular frame and not of all the frames in the video camera. So, how can I detect keypoints in all the frames on a live videocam?

Comment: Could you post a sample image from the camera?

Comment: I've added sample images. Please check and contribute. Thanks in advance!